# Any issue encountered after implementing SQL Server 2017 CU22?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, patching

We all are aware of SQL Server 2019 CU7 issue (Microsoft recalled the patch). Now I am cautiously optimistic to apply SQL Server 2017 CU22. I wanted to reach out to the SQL Server Community to know if anyone implemented a new update (CU22) and encounter any issue. I tried to research online but end up having nothing. Thank you all for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of weeks ago we patched to SQL2017 CU 22 in our all test and staging environment to begin with.

So far we did not see any issues. We were planning to go in prod by this weekend but from SQL 2019 CU 7 horror we prefer to make a change in our process to push updates to prod by at least a month now.

So as of now we have not see any issues on 2017. As a general guidance I will say patch to all lower environments and may be wait for some time , you decide that interval , and move ahead with the decision to patch.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I also patched a couple of test environment and I did not encounter any issue during patching and yes because of the same horror we are evaluating when to push this update in prod.